# Reformatting a list of elements using bash/sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed, csv-simple

I have a CSV file with a list like this:

```
URL,Domain,anchor
https://example1.com,Example1,Category1
```

I need to reformat this into HTML, like this:

```html
<li><a href="https://example1.com" title="Category1"> Example1 </a></li>
```

I've been tinkering with sed and awk for a while with no success. My best shot so far was to insert the first string before `https` and work manually from there. So I'm wondering if there's a better and faster way to do this.

Comment: What have you tried (show us). And a better way would be to use python and an CSV read library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added an extra line to the test file, called `eg.csv`:

```
URL,Domain,anchor
https://example1.com,Example1,Category1
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/693322/reformatting-a-list-of-elements-using-bash-sed,This question,Here
```

then wrote this basic AWK script:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F "," '
 NR == 1 { next } # Ignore titles
  {
     printf( "<li><a href=\"%s\" title=\"%s\"> %s </a></li>\n",
       $1, $3, $2 )
  }
' <eg.csv
```

and the result was:

```
$ ./fmt
<li><a href="https://example1.com" title="Category1"> Example1 </a></li>
<li><a href="https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/693322/reformatting-a-list-of-elements-using-bash-sed" title="Here"> This question </a></li>
```

which I hope satisfies your needs.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` :

```
sed '1d;s@\(^[^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\(.*\)@<li><a href="\1" title="\3"> \2 </a></li>@' test
```

Delete the heading lines (`1d`) and then split each lines at each commas to get the fields.

Insert between the fields obtained the html tags.